# is possible to add more to already appended data

Tags: jquery

is it possible to add more to an already appended data?
i have the code below which displays data when the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'page.php',
        data: vars,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#rows_of_data").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

now i want a form submission to process and display new rows found in the database below the already displayed data

```
$("#myform").submit(function () {
    // send via ajax
    // display new rows below the last row of the old data appended
});
```

Comment: Yeah you can, you already mentioned it. Append it to `#rows_of_data`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of `html()`.

```
$("#rows_of_data").append(data);
```

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of
>   each element in the set of matched elements.

In the above example, as you are matching on an id `#rows_of_data`, that is the only element in "the set of matched elements", and it get the contents of `data` appended to it as it's last child.

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxJAb/)

Comment: do you mean like this? $("#rows_of_data").append(new_data); ?

Comment: @kaydee if the name of the var containing what you want to append is `new_data`, then yes.

Comment: This also makes some assumptions about your DOM. `#rows_of_data` has to be a type of element that you want to append `new_data` directly to as the last child.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will be of help to others in this kind of problem

Comment: @kaydee, I've also added a simple demonstration of `append()`. If I've answered your question, please mark this as the answer using the checkmark to the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Possible, using [**`.append()`**](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$("#rows_of_data").append(data);
```

Your code should look like

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'page.php',
      data: vars,
      success: function(data){
         $("#rows_of_data").append(data);
      }
   });
});
```